# Can one or two links from popular sites with great reputation cause my site to rank noticably better in Google?

Tags: seo, backlinks, ranking, search-results

Maybe this is a question which stems admittedly out of lack of proper knowledge regarding backlinks despite being involved in the industry for a relatively long time.

I have launched a new blog, I continue working on it tirelessly 12+ hours a day 7 days a week, much to the dismay of my fiance, who threatened, "*its the blog or me...*"Well the blog is still going! Which brings me to my question.

Despite the young age of my blog (3-months) I am receiving exceptional traffic numbers via socialmedia, mostly thanks to a number of viral posts all with 6k-12k+ shares (humblebrag)

I was pleased, even shocked to discover that ***I have recently acquired a very good mention and backlink from a very high and authoritative website*** (MOZ-RANK 77) which is sort of on par with the dailytelegraph.co.uk (although that is not the site)

**My question**

I have received a couple of links, although not nearly as good as the above and I am sure many will agree that links such as the above are a rare find...my question...**can I expect to see any short to medium gains from the above link in terms of a serp perspective?**, or am I getting just a little to excited here...?

SideNote:

The niche is sport and the competition is rather stiff, not impossible to break, but definitely hard.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it's great to know that your hard work on your blog is paying off.

Considering the fact that links are counted as votes by SEs, links from reputable domains surely help in increasing your domain trust and authority in your niche.

Now coming to ranks; if the link has your targeted keyword in the anchor, you might or might not have a visible improvement in the ranks, it depends on your current rank for the keyword in the SERP and the competition ahead of you. For example, if you rank # 75 for the keyword, you might jump to #30, but if it already is within the top 10, you might not notice an immediate jump. You might need a couple more of such links to climb up the top 10 ladder. The higher you move up the ladder, the more link power you need to outperform the competitors. It also depends on the keyword you're searching with. That one link might place you at # 1 for a long tail keyword that has that targeted keyword in it.

Another impact of this link - you might expect to see improvement in rank for other pages that are linked from the page that gained the link. For example, if you gained the link on page A and it has links to page B, C & D, you might expect to see an improvement in ranks for the other pages since they also get a lion share of the link equity flowing in.

So there are certain factors that come into play here. The key is to keep gaining such links and making sure that the link equity is leveraged to your advantage and eventually you will see improvement in ranks and traffic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since most quality links link to the website name (more often than not) i.e. `www.myexample.com recently did a survey`...I suppose this opens up a whole new question of the value of an EMD, since essentially you are guarenteed to get your money word in the anchor phrase, with an EMD...agreed?

Comment: Yes, keywords in the domain name has a certain advantage, especially when we consider links from such high authority domains that either link using the official name or the domain name itself. However, going overboard with an EMD and picking up a 50 char domain name (to match your 4 letter phrase keyword) would not be recommended.

Comment: Well according to answer, which does make sense, I would argue it has a HUGE advantage - I never really understood why people were willing to pay thousands for an EMD but given the scenario above, since my domain name is pretty generic an EMD like say `bestrecipes.com` would have been MUCH, MUCH more valuable then just a `example.com` domain link...agreed? Would you say it's worth forking out a couple of thousand for a good EMD? (P.S im not in the food niche and have nothing to do with above domain just an example)

Comment: I have seen people spend thousands on EMDs and millions on brandable domains. An EMD domain name will take you to #1 just on the basis of the domain name itself when you're targeting an obscure keyword. But if you're playing in a competitive area, keywords in domains don't matter. Just because you see a business at #1 having an EMD domain doesn't mean he is #1 for that domain name. EMD domains had a greater impact in the earlier 2000 when it was heavily abused to influence ranks, but now they don't offer enough value to spend thousands on them. I'd rather go with a brandable domain over EMD.